# Java to C# can't Translate code (Matcher.group() & Matcher.replaceFirst)

Tags: java, c#, regex

I'm trying to translate a piece of code from java to c# but I can't find how to do it properly.
The piece i need to translate is this:
(getPattern returns a Pattern and data is a type that has a pattern variable and an enum (TokenType))

```
Match matcher = data.getPattern().matcher(str);//ThisLine
if (matcher.find())//ThisLine
{
     String token = matcher.group().trim();//This Line
     str = matcher.replaceFirst(""); //This Line

     if (data.getType() == TokenType.String_Literal)
     {
          return (lastToken = new Token(token.Substring(1, token.Length - 1), TokenType.String_Literal));
     }
     else
     {
          return (lastToken = new Token(token, data.getType()));
     }
}
```

I tried to translate it and got this:

```
 Match matcher = data.getRegex().Match(str);
 if (matcher.Success)
 {
      String token = matcher.Value.Trim();
      str = data.getRegex().Replace(token, "", 1);

      if (data.getType() == TokenType.String_Literal)
      {
           return (lastToken = new Token(token.Substring(1, token.Length - 1), TokenType.String_Literal));
      }
      else
      {
           return (lastToken = new Token(token, data.getType()));
      }
 }
```

I'm not at 100% understanding with the code but the parts all seem to be the correct replacement, they seem to do the same thing (when i read about them). They don't give any errors but the problem is that the c# code doesn't behave like the java code correctly.

Edit: I simply cannot find the c# equivalent of these lines of code.

```
Matcher matcher = A_Pattern.matcher(A_String)
matcher = matcher.group().trim();
boolean A_bool = matcher.find
String Another_String = matcher.replaceFirst("");
```

Comment: you need to post more code. What is `data`? what is  `getRegex()`? Where does `TokenType`  come from? What are you *really* trying to do? Also,  in C# you use  real properties as opposed to java's horrible `getXXX()` and `setXXX()` syntax. C# is a modern language.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `the C# code doesn't behave` - what's the difference? In  what  way is the result wrong? Please specify.

Comment: Please show your regex patten,and show the result of `str` value both in java and c#

Comment: Where is the original Java code?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_EQ5jdrgOlU&index=3&list=PLAF3anQEEkzRuJ7UW82CmSEtT6g-J4Q_p Im folowing this series and translating it to c# (also changing how the new language works at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

The trick is the [numbered parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-int32)) in `rx.Replace`. only the first match is used.

```cs
String pattern = @"The";
Regex rx = new Regex(pattern);

string text = "the The quick the brown fox  fox jumps over the lazy dog dog.";

string result = rx.Replace(text, "" , 1);
Console.WriteLine (result.Trim());
```